# Video chat feature

Tags: android

I  searched a lot and didn't find the answer of my question.
I want to add to my android app video chat feature.
I am writing app for version 2.2 and latest.
Can I provide this feature or not and if I can,please write some link of code 
which I need.

And also, I have read [this](http://coenraets.org/blog/2010/07/video-chat-for-android-in-30-lines-of-code/) tutorial and I want to  know is this real working app and if yes how can I merge this to my native app code?